# Get font from the project path

Tags: c#, path, directory

I have downloaded a .ttf file that I need to use in my web application. And I'm just wondering if what is the best way to tell the right path of this file that inside my project.

Currently I'm using this.

```
string fontPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot") + "\\fonts\\ARIALUNI.ttf";
```

But when I deployed this in a server, it seems that the server does not have this kind of file and I need this tff file to display english and chinese characters. What I did was to download this file and include it in my project. How do I know its path and even if I deploy it to the server or publish it. It will still be included and be called without errors? Any ideas? Thanks!

By the way. Here's where I put my .ttf file.
[image]

Comment: yes. mvc web application

Comment: Fonts don't work on the web the same way as they do on desktop applications.

Comment: It works when I run it on my local. I just need to determine the path of the file that I included in my project.

Answer (score -1):

right click your font and go to properties => set Copy to output directory as **"Copy if newer"**

[image]

```
String fontPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "ARIALUNI.ttf");
```

Comment: How do I know its path? I need to know the path.

Comment: Will this work if I publish it and deploy it on the server? I will try anyways.